# Bibliography not rendering in R Studio

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bibtex

I am very new to LaTex and R Markdown and I've been desperately searching for a solution and have not found anything helpful.  I am writing a LaTex document under R Markdown file and my YAML header is the following;

```
---
linestretch: 2
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \setlength{\parindent}{3em}
  - \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
bibliography: bibliography.bib
---

# References
```

however when I knit my file my bibliography is not rendering.  Everything compiles nicely without error, but nothing is printed after the `# References` header.  My bibliography.bib file is appropriately saved in the same file as where I have saved this LaTex document.  I can't seem to figure this out.

Also if this helps by bibliography.bib file is as follows;

```
@Book{ref1,
  title     = {Survival Analysis: A Self-Learning Text},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year      = {2005},
  author    = {David G. Kleinbaum, Mitchel Klein},
  editor    = {M. Gail, K. Krickeberg, J. Samet, A. Tsiatis, W. Wong},
  edition   = {2nd},
}

@Misc{ref2,
  title  = {pseudo: Pseudo - observations},
  author = {{Maja Pohar Perme} and Mette Gerster},
  year   = {2012},
  note   = {R package version 1.1},
  url    = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=pseudo},
}
```

A solution to this problem will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Of course you have to cite one of your references ... add `@ref1` after the YAML header and before `#References` and it should work...

Comment: Huh, wasn't aware of this important detail.  Thank you very much, this is much appreciated!  So just to confirm, there's no way of rendering the bibliography with a particular reference without citing that source beforehand?